# How to integrate Yii with Wordpress / Digital Access Pass

Tags: php, authentication, yii

I'm building a small web app to sit within an existing Wordpress membership site.

At the moment, all of the content is protected using Digital Access Pass, which handles user authentication and content protection.

I'm thinking of using Yii for this, and installing it into a subdirectory of the Wordpress site.

My plan is to have this layout:

www.site.com (wordpress blog)

www.site.com/members (content protected with the Digital Access Pass membership solution, set up in Wordpress)

www.site.com/members/app (yii folder - protected by DAP, but not set up in Wordpress)

I don't want to do a full integration, as I'm using a lot of Ajax and that doesn't look like it will work too well from the examples I've seen.

What I'd like is to use DAP to protect the pages and handle authentication, and also to pass the logged- in userid to Yii so I can use as a key to store user preferences, user data, etc.

The way DAP works is that you just insert the following code into any page you want to protect, and then you can access a User object that contains the info I need.

```
<?php
    include_once "../dap/dap-config.php";
    $user = null;

if( !Dap_Session::isLoggedIn() ) { 
    //send viewer to login page
    header("Location:".SITE_URL_DAP.Dap_Config::get("LOGIN_URL"));
    exit;
}
else if( Dap_Session::isLoggedIn() ) { 
    //get userid
    $session = Dap_Session::getSession();
    $user = $session->getUser();
    $user = Dap_User::loadUserById($user->getId()); //reload User object
    if(!isset($user)) {
        //send viewer to login page
        header("Location:".SITE_URL_DAP.Dap_Config::get("LOGIN_URL"));
        exit;
    } else {
        $userProducts = Dap_UsersProducts::loadProducts($user->getId());
    }
}
?>
```

How do I go about implementing this in Yii?

Comment: I am working on the doing the integration with DAP/WordPress and CakePhp. Quick comment, you don't need to your app in the member folder it can be anywhere and DAP will protect it. Did you ever get your integration to work?

Comment: No, I didn't use Yii in the end, I handrolled my own MVC.  It was a simple application, and I didn't know Yii very well at the time.  If I were building it now, I would probably use the CUserIdentity approach outlined below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by taking a look at [Yii Filters](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller#filter)

You should be able to put your code in the filter and then have it run (much like the [built-in Access Control Filter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#access-control-filter))

And then, if you're going to build your app truly Yii-like, you might want to work on wrapping the DapUser in a [CUserIdentity](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#defining-identity-class) class and making it work well with the CWebUser object.  It would take a bit of work, but then you'd truly have easy access to the user info in all Yii objects.

Good luck!